# WPF TreeView keep list of elements visible on screen

Tags: wpf, treeview

I am trying to get the elements in a tree view that is visible on the screen.

If I have the following elements:

- A1

  - A1.1
  - A1.2
- B1

  - B1.1
- C
- D
- E

Let's say only elements A1, A1.1, A1.2 and B1 are visible on the screen, I want to get a list of these. When scrolling this list must be maintained, so that all elements that disappears from the screen is removed from the list and all elements that appear will be added to the list.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As I guess you want to visualize your TreeView, so you should not do it by yourself just enable TreeView virtualization like so:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Data1}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
```